# loop within loop (with more detail)

Tags: loops, tcl, frame, distance

I have a 229 residue protein and I need to measure from the center of mass of residue 1-12 (individually) to every other atom, residue 13 onwards, I also need this for each frame. so far I have this

```
set pro [atomselect top "resid 1 and not water and not ion"] 
set atom [atomselect top "index 207"] 
set nf [molinfo top get numframes] 
set outfile [open test207.dat w] 
for {set i 0} {$i < $nf} {incr i} { 
    puts "frame $i of $nf" 
    $pro frame $i 
    $atom frame $i 
    set com1 [measure center $pro weight mass] 
    set com2 [measure center $atom weight mass] 
    set distance [veclength [vecsub $com1 $com2]] 
    puts $outfile "$i $distance" 
}
```

this is working to the extent that it's measure the distance between the first atom of residue 13 to the com of residue 1 for all frames, but I'm unsure as to how to put a second loop that will loop for every atom, instead of running the script thousands of times (changing the atom number each time) resulting in thousands of files.

Is there a way to loop for each atom and for each frame in the same script?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Do you want all `puts` to go into one file? How would you select atoms? You're obviously using some Tcl library that I - and possibly other users - are not familiar with - which one is it?

Comment: I think that some example output (with dummy values if possible?) would be nice to make it easier to understand what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is how you put two loops...

```
for (set j 0} {$j < $..} {incr j} {
   for {set i 0} {$i < $nf} {incr i} { 

   };   # inner loop ends
};      # outer loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you are trying to do?

```
for {set resid 1} {$resid < 10} {incr resid} {
    set atomkey [format "resid %d and not water and not ion" $resid]
    puts $atomkey

    set filename [format "test%d.dat" $resid]
    set outfile [open $filename w] 

    # Do stuff
    close $outfile

}
```

This results in `atomkey` and `filename` being built with the value of resid embeded in it. So this type of technique will allow you to create your key strings and file names.  If you can't generate the values using a for loop then you can also look at the foreach loop:

```
foreach resid [list 1 2 4 6 7 99 12] {
    set atomkey [format "resid %d and not water and not ion" $resid]
    puts $atomkey
}
```

You can build the compound values just using set, but I like to use format as I'm a C programmer at heart.

```
set atomkey "resid $resid and.."
```

Comment: It might be an idea to factor out the code to do stuff on a single file into its own procedure. Makes it easier to understand, fix, test and stuff like that.